# How to return thread safe byte[]?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I'm sorry to post such a noob question but I can't find the answer. I'm not very good at unit testing yet so I'm not sure about this. Is this the best way to return a byte[] that is thread safe? Also is it okay to initialize the array here and modify it in another thread?

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetData()
{
    var _buffer = new byte[1024];
    try { await Task.Run(() => ModifyArray(_buffer)); }
    catch { return null;}

    return _buffer.ToArray();
}
```

I know the ModifyArray(byte[]) should return the value but it's actually a Socket Receive Method. 
I am also looking at:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetData()
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
    {
        var _buffer = new byte[1024];
        try { ModifyArray(_buffer); }
        catch { return null;}

        return _buffer.ToArray();
    });
}
```

or should I move the ToArray() to the outside like this

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetData()
{
    return (Task.Run(() => {...});).ToArray();
}
```

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The marker for thread-unsafe code is a variable that's read by one thread and written by another.  There's no obvious sign of that in the posted snippet, _buffer is a local variable and every thread has its own local variables.  We can't see what ModifyArray() does, it could be thread-unsafe.  May well be since it uses a completely uninitialized array.  But as posted there is no obvious source of trouble.

Comment: @HansPassant The ModifyArray() is really Receive() in the Socket class. I thought any thread can read a variable but only one can change it? Is there any difference between my second and third code blocks I wrote?

Comment: Threadsafe *against what failure mode*?  What's the problem you're trying to avoid? My experience has been that no two people have the same definition for "threadsafe", so be more specific if you want a solid answer.

Comment: This is not related to your question, but, pretty please, never do this: `catch { return null; }`. If something bad happens, you want to know as much as possible, so it's not a good idea to hide any information you might have about the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a copy of an array is necessary if you want to return a snapshot of your array, but you don't want your caller to modify your internal state.

But that's not your case. You create a new array in each call of your method, and you don't care of the caller modifies it or not (assuming `ModifyArray()` does not store the array).

That means the following code should be okay:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetData()
{
    var _buffer = new byte[1024];
    await Task.Run(() => ModifyArray(_buffer));
    return _buffer;
}
```

Another option would be to use the closest thing .Net has to “readonly array”: `IReadOnlyList<T>` (new in .Net 4.5):

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<byte>> GetData()
{
    var _buffer = new byte[1024];
    await Task.Run(() => ModifyArray(_buffer));
    return _buffer;
}
```

Also, using `await Task.Run()` like this is [often not a good idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). If you want to use asynchrony to the fullest, use a truly asynchronous method. If you want to offload some computation from the UI thread, do that in the UI code, not in your library.